# How to pass data between two Activities without a direct navigation link between them?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have 3 activities:

[image: diagram]

1. `ActivityOne` fetches some BLE info, verifies it, then launches `ActivityTwo` on success.
2. `ActivityTwo` uses a `Fragment` that displays a `RecyclerView` of `Foo` items. Each `Foo` has an associated click listener to launch `ActivityThree`, passing the `Foo.id` with `intent.putLongExtra`.
3. `ActivityThree` needs access to the BLE info.

Since the `Fragment` from `ActivityTwo` is launching `ActivityThree` (and doesn't know about EXTRA data from the parent activity), what's the right way to go about getting the BLE info into `ActivityThree`?

ActivityTwo is simply a container for the layout and the `Fragment` that does the heavy lifting. All the other examples I've found of passing info around rely on `Interfaces` or programmatically creating the `Fragments` (rather than using the data binding and xml infrastructure that Android provides).

What am I supposed to do to get the BLE info in `ActivityThree` this situation? It's just a small `ByteArray`, so I don't want anything as complicated as a `Service` running in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try getActivity().getIntent() in ActivityTwo's Fragment? After getting data in Fragment with it, you can put it for ActivityThree

Comment: OK, thanks, this would be a possible way (though couples the Fragment to the Activity, which I guess is OK since I don't need to reuse it)

Comment: And for the kotlin users: `activity?.intent!!.getByteArrayExtra(EXTRA_SOMEDATA)`

Answer (score 0):

You can also put the small byteAray inside the application Singleton.

Assuming you have your manifest like this one

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/playstore_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
    ....
</application>
```

Then in your MyApplication class put something like

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {

    public static yourTypeOfData myData;
}
```

in ActivityA

```
MyApplication.myData= dataToBepassedToActivityC
```

in ActivityC

```
dataINeed = MyApplication.myData;
//then wipe out the data from your app to avoid memory leak
MyApplication.myData = null;
```

Be aware , anyway ,this is not the best approach at all, that would be to implements services or passing these data between activity B

Comment: Can you explain this a bit better? (how to do it?) I haven't heard of this tactic before.

Answer (score 0):

for 3 activity usually used bundle (EXTRA)
but another way is to use Android-Application Class (Singleton) like this:

**create your app class with your variable you want to access it from all application:**

```
public class App extends Application {
public static List<StringWithTag> provinces = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

**initialize your class in AndroidManifest:**

```
<application
        android:name=".App"
        ...
```

and finally, use it everywhere you want like

```
App.provinces = ...;
```

Android-Application Class run in the background with start application and die when the application completely closed
and remember don't use a lot of static variables because of memory leak